# What book is about a teenage girl who likes fire and has "brown silver and gold" hair?

Tags: identification-request

She lives in some kind of fishing town or port town with evil foster parents who call her a "wharf rat" and plot to frame her for arson. I *thought* it was called Firestarter but when I search for Firestarter all I can find is Firestarter by Stephen King, which is nothing like the book I'm looking for. When I search for phrases in the book I find nothing. The only other thing I can remember is that my sister had this book when she was a teenager, and it was written by somebody who wrote lots of books for teenage girls.

Comment: For future reference, while not infallible, ChatGPT4 does a great job at identifying references.

Answer (score 10):

This must be the trilogy by Caroline B. Cooney that's now called the *Losing Christina* series, consisting of the three books [*Fog*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/93783), [*Snow*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/93787.Snow), and [*The Fire*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/93780.The_Fire).

From [this discussion of *Fog*](https://electricliterature.com/double-dare-point-horror/) (emphasis mine):

> Our hero Christina is thirteen, excited to leave her tiny island off the coast of Maine to attend high school on the mainland, along with her older friend Anya and two boring boys. Christina is brave and stubborn and has **naturally tri-colored hair — brown, silver, and gold**, (yeah, I don’t know either) — but all this is meager protection against the horror we already know she will encounter: that of being a poor kid in a school of rich dickheads.

> As the Shevvingtons sadly say, “We always thought she would become a **wharf rat** and now she has.” “Wharf rat,” of course, is the book’s pejorative for a particular kind of working class girl.

From a Goodreads review of *Fog*:

> The guest rooms in the inn are pretty and quaint, but the children live in an unfurnished room at the top of a rickety and steep staircase where it's drafty and cold. Mr. Shevvington and Mrs. Shevvington, their caretakers, are also the principal and the English teacher of the school, respectively. They give new students surveys, asking them about their fears, and English assignments describing what they think it might feel like to die or have their parents abandon them.

From the Goodreads summary of *The Fire*:

> Christina knows the Shevvingtons have left a trail of hollowed-out, lost girls in mental hospitals across the country, and she has seen the secret files that prove it. But the Shevvingtons are determined to destroy the evidence ­ and Christina. This time, they'll use fire. They stuff her pocketbook full of matchbooks, scribble flames over her class notes ­ anything they can do to make it look like Christina is obsessed with fire and a danger to herself and others.

I found this by searching for `fantasy novel girl "wharf rat"`, where the 10th result on the web was [this page](https://electricliterature.com/double-dare-point-horror/) confirming both the "wharf rat" detail and the multi-coloured hair detail.